Vivado design checkpoint
I am quite new to this.
Hopping into an existing project, which had both bin and dcp files commited in to git. These have constant conflicts, which makes sense to me. As generated files, my take is that they should not be in version control.
So, I removed the top.dcp file from the repo (as well as top.bin). It was quite deep into a directory structure.
But now, Vivado complains that it cannot find it. "Incremental checkpoint file does not exist".
My understanding was that this file was used as some kind of cache, so that the whole design wouldn't need resynthesizing at the least change in the source. In that case, Vivado should just generate it if missing?
I tried to change the project synthesis settings to "Specify design checkpoint" and "New design checkpoint" to "top.dcp", but the complaint remains.

is the dcp file only generated from source, and should not be in version control?
why does Vivado require the actual file, if it should be able to generate it by itself?
how do I make sure the file generates on demand, and don't complain if missing? My plan is then to add these to .gitignore.


Yes, the DCP is generated from source and can help to speed up synthesis by reusing the output of a previous run. It's no problem if it's not there. It will just do a full synthesis run and regenerate it, and you can ignore the warning. So you don't need to commit it to your repo unless maybe you want other computers to be able to reuse the synth results.
I'd suggest setting the 'Automatically use the checkpoint from the previous run' option so you can still take advantage of incremental synthesis when you rebuild on the same computer.
